# need help with this compile error for getline function error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::istream&, char&)'|

Tags: c++, getline

I have a source code file with getline function in it and I receive and error when I compile it (code and error below).  My problem is that I copied and pasted the whole function from an already compiled and working program (included below as well).  I also have the getline function in 2 other source code files in the program, both of which compile fine.  I am fairly new to programming and just started c++ programing (much better at Java) so try to keep answers simple.  I looked through some of the already posted questions and answers here (and google) but all the ones I found the answers say that the parameters for the function are not correct.  But I know they are correct here because it works in the other program just fine.  Also as you can see in the working file the only #included is iostream and it works, that's with g++ complier in Code::Blocks.  I made sure to include all the variables/constants needed as well.

Here is the code for the function and file I am getting the error from.  The parts I am refering to are marked by 3 *** (sorry best I could do).  The error is reprinted at the bottom of post as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include "candidates.h"

using namespace std;

int nCandidatesInPrimary;

int delegatesForThisState;

const int maxCandidates = 10;

int delegatesWon[maxCandidates];

int totalVotes;

int totalDelegates = 0;

int votesForCandidate[maxCandidates];

string candidate[maxCandidates];

int nCandidates;

string candidateNames;

void readCandidates ()
{
  cin >> nCandidates;
  string line;
  getline (cin, line);

  for (int i = 0; i < nCandidates; ++i)
    {
      ***getline (cin, candidateNames[i]);***
      delegatesWon[i] = 0;
    }
}

int findCandidate (std::string name)
{
  int result = nCandidates;
  for (int i = 0; i < nCandidates && result == nCandidates; ++i)
    if (candidateNames[i] == name)
      result = i;
  return result;
}

void printCandidateReport (int candidateNum)
{
  int requiredToWin = (2 * totalDelegates + 2) / 3; // Note: the +2 rounds up
  if (delegatesWon[candidateNum] >= requiredToWin)
    cout << "* ";
  else
    cout << "  ";
  cout << delegatesWon[candidateNum] << " " << candidateNames[candidateNum] << endl;
}

void assignDelegatesToCandidates ()
{
  int remainingDelegates = delegatesForThisState;
  for (int i = 0; i < nCandidatesInPrimary; ++i)
    {
      int candidateNum = findCandidate(candidate[i]);
      int nDel = (delegatesForThisState * votesForCandidate[i] + (totalVotes-1)) / totalVotes;
      if (nDel > remainingDelegates)
    nDel = remainingDelegates;
      delegatesWon[candidateNum] += nDel;
      remainingDelegates -= nDel;
    }
}
```

here is the code from the already working program.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Max # of candidates permitted by this program
const int maxCandidates = 10;

// Names of the candidates participating in this state's primary
string candidate[maxCandidates];

// Names of all candidates participating in the national election
std::string candidateNames[maxCandidates];

// How many delegates are assigned to the state being processed
int delegatesForThisState;

// How many delgates have been won by each candidate
int delegatesWon[maxCandidates];

// How many candidates in the national election?
int nCandidates;

// How many candidates in the primary for the state being processed
int nCandidatesInPrimary;

// How many states participate in the election
int nStates;

// How many delegates in the election (over all states)
int totalDelegates = 0;

// How many votes were cast in the primary for this state
int totalVotes;

// How many votes wone by each candiate in this state's primary
int votesForCandidate[maxCandidates];


int findCandidate (std::string name);

/**
 * For the most recently read primary, determine how many delegates have
 * been won by each candidate.
 */
void assignDelegatesToCandidates ()
{
  int remainingDelegates = delegatesForThisState;
  for (int i = 0; i < nCandidatesInPrimary; ++i)
    {
      int candidateNum = findCandidate(candidate[i]);
      int nDel = (delegatesForThisState * votesForCandidate[i] + (totalVotes-1)) / totalVotes;
      if (nDel > remainingDelegates)
    nDel = remainingDelegates;
      delegatesWon[candidateNum] += nDel;
      remainingDelegates -= nDel;
    }
}



/**
 * Find the candidate with the indicated name. Returns the array index
 * for the candidate if found, nCandidates if it cannot be found.
 */
int findCandidate (std::string name)
{
  int result = nCandidates;
  for (int i = 0; i < nCandidates && result == nCandidates; ++i)
    if (candidateNames[i] == name)
      result = i;
  return result;
}


/**
 * Print the report line for the indicated candidate
 */
void printCandidateReport (int candidateNum)
{
  int requiredToWin = (2 * totalDelegates + 2) / 3; // Note: the +2 rounds up
  if (delegatesWon[candidateNum] >= requiredToWin)
    cout << "* ";
  else
    cout << "  ";
  cout << delegatesWon[candidateNum] << " " << candidateNames[candidateNum] << endl;
}


/**
 * read the list of candidate names, initializing their delegate counts to 0.
 */
void readCandidates ()
{
  cin >> nCandidates;
  string line;
  getline (cin, line);

  for (int i = 0; i < nCandidates; ++i)
    {
      ***getline (cin, candidateNames[i]);***//already working
      delegatesWon[i] = 0;
    }
}


/**
 * read the info on one state's primaries
 */
void readState ()
{
  totalVotes = 0;
  cin >> nCandidatesInPrimary >> delegatesForThisState;
  totalDelegates += delegatesForThisState;  // "x += y" is a shorthand for "x = x + y"
  string word, line;
  getline (cin, line);
  for (int i = 0; i < nCandidatesInPrimary; ++i)
    {
      cin >> votesForCandidate[i];
      totalVotes = totalVotes + votesForCandidate[i];

      cin >> word;
      getline (cin, line);
      candidate[i] = word + line;
    }
}



/**
 * Generate the report on the national primary election.
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  readCandidates();
  int nStates;
  cin >> nStates;
  for (int i = 0; i < nStates; ++i)
    {
      readState();
      assignDelegatesToCandidates();
    }
  for (int i = 0; i < nCandidates; ++i)
    {
      printCandidateReport(i);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::istream&, char&)'|

Comment: really, that's the best you could do? how about posting a 5 line code that has the same problem?

Comment: I put all that code there to try and help understand the problem and to weed out things I know are not the problem, like #include <iostream> something like that, that I have already tried and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you intended candidateNames to be declared as a `vector<string> candidateNames;`

```
vector<string> candidateNames;

void readCandidates ()
{
  cin >> nCandidates;
  string line;
  getline (cin, line);
  candidateNames.resize(nCandidates);    
  for (int i = 0; i < nCandidates; ++i)
    {
       getline (cin, candidateNames[i]);

    }
}
```

Comment: I did not intend that to be a vector, it works fine in the other program the way it is.  I can try to change it but I would like to know why it works in the other program and not this one before I do.

Comment: @gimpdogg The entire logic of the readCandidates() of the function as well as the name (readCandidates) implies it should read several candidates name, hence a vector. Also you are using an array `std::string candidateNames[maxCandidates];` in your working example. A vector is an improvement to the array.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks but I did find the problem already.  It was in my header file, I forgot the [] after candidatesNames.

Answer (score 0):

`candidateNames` is a single string, not a collection of strings. What about setting up a vector of them?

`std::vector<string> candidateNames;`

And then before your `for` loop:

`candidateNames.resize(nCandidates);`

Comment: I have never done a vector, also this is part of a homework assignment, that is why I have the already working program(single file).  We are suppose to just separate the functions into other source files, these variables are used in the other files as well.  I can try but I don't know how this will affect the other parts of the program and generally with these homeworks we don't have to modify them like that(generally).  Also why would it compile fine in the already working program (before I try and change it all to a vector)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to

```
#include <string>
```

It's likely that the other headers have pulled in the string class itself, but not all the supporting functions such as `getline` overloads that accept `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I might have been unfair when posting this question.  I was able to find the problem, it was in my header file, I messed up the variables there.  for candidateNames[] I forgot the [] at the end in the header file.  And since I didn't include that file in my post you couldn't see that.  Thanks for the help though.